Simple method to Replace or Add Text of Variable in Powershell
I'm doing something related to adb fastboot in Windows.
$id  = 'c9aaa9c70321'
$com = 'adb reboot bootloader'

If there is more than one device, the command $com=... above not working and getting an error. And command adb ... in powershell not work too. Must use ./adb .....
So. I want to replace $com with Specific Phone ID ./adb -s $ID reboot bootloader
$com = $com.Replace("$($com.Split()[0])","./$($com.Split()[0]) -s $($ID)")
$com; pause

I use replace and split.
I think my method is too long.
So, is there any simpler code to replace $com variable ?

Unclear : Why don't you just assign a new value to the variable?

This example just one. How if multiple.... assign multiple value... not

Not too sure what you want/need simplified there. Just use a variable for $($com.Split()[0]) and it'll already be simplier and more optimized.

@Mr.Key7 $com = "./$($com.Split()[0]) -s $($ID) $($com.Split()[1..2])" might suffice. As suggested, omitting the replace() method and just splitting to build out the string variable as desired.  You can simplify but add as separate variables which means more variable less optimized, but simplified code perhaps as such $com1 = "$($com.Split()[0])"; $com2 = $($com.Split()[1..2]); $com = "./$com1 -s $ID $com2"; When code is too long, making separate variable may help too give what it desired even though it means loading more variables into the code/memory.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle thank you for providing different code

Yes, there is a simpler way to replace the text in the $com variable. You can use the following code:
PowerShell:
=com = "./adb -s $id " + $com.Split(' ')1
This code splits the $com string into an array using the space character as the delimiter, takes the second element (index 1), and concatenates it with the desired prefix "./adb -s $id ".
Here's a breakdown of how it works:

$com.Split(' ') splits the string into an array using space as the delimiter 1 takes the second element of the array (index 1), which is the command "reboot bootloader"

"./adb -s $id " + concatenates the desired prefix with the command


This code is simpler and more efficient than using the Replace and Split methods.

Thanks. Please edit the answer. "./adb -s $id " + $com.Split(' ') the output ./adb -s c9aaa9c70321 adb reboot bootloader. i need ./adb -s c9aaa9c70321 reboot bootloader
